# A basic form program PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a little problem with my first program in PHP and i'm asking for your help

my POST is not working

this is the html part

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="fr-FR" />
<title>Vérification de formulaire</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="feuilleDeStyle.css" media="all"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.formvalidation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formulairecontact").formValidation({
        alias       : "name",
        required    : "accept",
        err_list    : true
    }); 

});
</script>
   </head>
   <body>
<form id="formulairecontact" method="post" action="cible.php" >
    <fieldset>
            <legend>Ajouter un offre</legend>
            <p class="error"></p>
            <label for="id">l'ID</label> 
            <input required="true" type="text" mask="numeric" name="id" value=""/>
            <label  for="adresse">l'adresse</label>
            <input type="text" required="true" name="adresse" size=50 value=""/>
            <label for="ville">Ville</label> 
            <input required="true" type="text" name="ville" value=""/>
        <label  for="classe">Classe</label>
            <select required="true" name="classe" id="classe">
                <option></option>   
            <option>Choix 1</option>
            <option>Choix 2</option>
            <option>Choix 3</option>
            <option>Choix 4</option>
            <option>Choix 5</option>
        </select>
        <label  for="disponibilite">Disponibilité</label>
            <select required="true" defval="" name="disponibilite">
            <option></option>   
            <option>Choix 1</option>
            <option>Choix 2</option>
            <option>Choix 3</option>
            <option>Choix 4</option>
            <option>Choix 5</option>
        </select>
        <label  for="etat">Etat d'entrée</label>
            <select required="true" defval="" name="etat">
                <option></option>   
            <option>Choix 1</option>
            <option>Choix 2</option>
            <option>Choix 3</option>
            <option>Choix 4</option>
            <option>Choix 5</option>
        </select>
            <label for="salon">Salons</label> 
            <input mask="numeric" required="true" type="int" name="salon" size="5" value=""/>
            <label for="chambre">Chambres</label> 
            <input mask="numeric" required="true" type="int" name="chambre" size="5" value=""/>
            <label for="salle-eau">Salles d'eau</label> 
            <input mask="numeric" required="true" type="int" name="salle-eau" size="5" value=""/>
            <label for="salle-douche">Salles de douche</label> 
            <input mask="numeric" required="true" type="int" name="salle-douche" size="5" value=""/>
            <label for="salle-bain">Salles de bain</label> 
            <input mask="numeric" required="true" type="int" name="salle-bain" size="5" value=""/>
            <label for="cuisine">Cuisines</label> 
            <input mask="numeric" required="true" type="int" name="cuisine" size="5" value=""/>
            <label for="autre">Autres</label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="25" required="true" name="autre" ></textarea> 
            <label for="equipement">Equipements</label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="25" required="true" name="equipement" ></textarea> 
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="25" required="true" name="description" ></textarea>  
            <button type="submit">Ajouter l'offre</button>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

```
<?php
include('connexion.php');
$id=$_POST['id'];
$adresse=$_POST['adresse'];
$ville=$_POST['ville'];
$classe=$_POST['classe'];
$disponibilite=$_POST['disponibilite'];
$etat=$_POST['etat'];
$salon=$_POST['salon'];
$chambre=$_POST['chambre'];
$eau=$_POST['salle-eau'];
$douche=$_POST['salle-douche'];
$bain=$_POST['salle-bain'];
$cuisine=$_POST['cuisine'];
$equipement=$_POST['equipement'];
$autre=$_POST['autre'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO agence (ID,Adresse,Ville,Classe,Disponibilite,Etat,Salon,Chambre,Salleeau,douche,bain,Cuisine,Autre,Equipement,Description) 
VALUES                  ('$id','$adresse','$ville','$classe','$disponibilite','$etat','$salon','$chambre','$eau','$douche','$bain','$cuisine','$autre','$equipement','$description')";
$result = @mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br />\n".mysql_error());?>
```

My problem is that when i enter data to the form and submit it a page displayed that i have this error: \n".mysql_error() meaning that the query to the database has not succeeded i checked the name and everything but nothing works.and the POST is not.

Comment: Where is the code for the mysql query?

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are obsolete. If you're learning PHP now, you should be learning to use the PDO library not the old `mysql` library.

Comment: You should provide the code of `connexion.php` because the code that you've posted does not contain any mysql calls that might fail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your php try the below:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

to make sure your html form is well received in your server side. then try to escape your entry you should be good, if that did not solve your problem, then you probably have a problem with your sql connection.

And in your code it seems that you are missing `mysql_connect` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: I have the sql connection script in a separate page (connexion.php)

Comment: what is the error you are getting ? do you see something in your web page ?

Comment: I'm getting this error "mysql.error" the query didn't reach out

Comment: You probably have a problem with your connexion.php code make sure you are connecting to the right server and port try to connect to your db using a client like sqlYog or heidiSql

Comment: Thank you all, the problem is solved. I have just restarted my Laptop